# Working with huge maps (putIfAbsent)

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

I have this Map definition :

```
TreeMap <String, Set<Integer>>
```

It may contain millions of entries, and I also need a "natural order" (that's why I've chosen a TreeMap, though I could write a Comparator if needed).

So, what I have to do in order to add an element to the map is :

1. Check if a key already exists.
2. If not, create a new Set and add the value.
3. If it exists, I have to add the value to the Set

I have this implementation which works fine :

```
private void addToMap (String key, Integer value){
    Set<Integer> vs = dataMap.get(key);
    if (vs == null){
        vs = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        dataMap.put(key,vs);
    }
    vs.add(value);
}
```

But I would like to avoid searching for the key and then putting the element if it doesn't exist (it will perform a new search over the huge map).

I think I could use `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent` method, but then :

1. I will not have the natural ordering of the keys (and I will need to perform a sort on the millions keys)
2. I may have (I don't know) additional overhead because of synchronization over the ConcurrentHashMap, and in my situation my process is single threaded and it may impact performance.

Reading this post : [Java map.get(key) - automatically do put(key) and return if key doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334061/java-map-getkey-automatically-do-putkey-and-return-if-key-doesnt-exist)
there's an answer that talks about Guava `MapMaker.makeComputingMap` but looks like the method is not there anymore.

Performance is critical in this situation (as always :D), so please let me know your recommendations.

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE :**
Thanks a lot for so many helping answers in just some minutes.
(I don't know which one to select as the best).

I will do some performance tests on the suggestions (TreeMultiMap, ConcurrentSkipListMap, TreeSet + HashMap) and update with the results. I will select the one with the best performance then, as I'd like to select all three of them but I cannot.

**NOTE2**

So, I did some performance testing with 1.5 million entries, and these are the results :

- ConcurrentSkipListMap, it doesn't work as I expected, because it replaces the existing value with the new empty set I provided. I thought it was setting the value only if it the key doesn't exist, so I cannot use this one. (my mistake).
- TreeSet + HashMap, works fine but doesn't give the best performance. It is like 1.5 times slower than TreeMap alone or TreeMultiMap.
- TreeMultiMap gives the best performance, but it is almost the same as the TreeMap alone. I will check this one as the answer.

Again, thanks a lot for your contributions and help.

Comment: If performance is critical I wouldn't use a TreeSet of Integer, I would find a more light weight structure like TIntArrayList or something which wraps `int` values.  I would also use a HashMap as its look up is O(1) instead of O(log N).  If you also need to keep the keys sorted, I would use a second collection for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Concurrent map does not do magic, it checks the existence and then inserts if not exists.
- Guava have MultiMaps, for example `TreeMultiMap` can be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is critical I wouldn't use a TreeSet of Integer, I would find a more light weight structure like TIntArrayList or something which wraps `int` values.  I would also use a HashMap as its look up is O(1) instead of O(log N).  If you also need to keep the keys sorted, I would use a second collection for that.

I agree that putIfAbsent on ConcurrentHashMap is overkill and get/put on a HashMap is likely to be the fastest option.

ConcurrentSkipListMap might be a good option to use putIfAbsent, but it I would make sure its not slower.

BTW Even worse than doing a get/put is creating a HashSet you don't need.

Comment: PutIfAbsent is not overkill, its threadsafe. If you work with threads there is no way around that.

Comment: @TwoThe The OP specifically stated "in my situation my process is single threaded ".

Comment: @TwoThe It is even overkill in a multithreaded case as it creates a HasHSet needlessly just in case it needs it even if it doesn't (which creates a HashMap and an Entry[]. So three objects you most likely don't need.

Comment: I have difficulties with the word 'overkill' on things that potentially slow down execution by 0.000001%. It is ok to notice that this is slower than non-concurrent maps, but the actual gain/loss is completely dependent on the usage.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I will change the TreeSet, no problem there. But I will need to traverse the map in natural order of the keys. Even with this requisite is it better to use a HashMap than a TreeMap?

Comment: @richardtz Why not use both. a TreeSet for the keys in sorted order and  HashMap for looking them up.  I assume the traversal of the keys is not done too often at for millions of keys that won't be cheap.

Answer (score 2):

PutIfAbsent has the benefit of concurrency, that is: if many threads call this at the same time, they don't have to wait (it doesn't use synchronized internally). However this comes at a minor cost of execution speed, so if you work only single-threaded, this will slow things down.

If you need this sorted, try the [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).

Comment: +1 ConcurrentSkipListMap is worth remembering in a multi-threaded context.